# How to launch an Activity from another Application in Android 30

Tags: java, android

I have been using the following code to open my other app from within my app. This code works upto Android 29 devices but this code does not work in Android 30 devices. Can somebody please help me make it work for Android 30 as well. Thanks

```
    case R.id.btAudio:

        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getString("com.android.audioapp"));
        Intent uin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioInstall.class);
        if (launchIntent != null) {
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        } else {
            startActivity(uin);
        }
        this.finish();
        break;
```

Comment: What is R.string.audiopackagename?  Are you assuming a specific package is installed on the device that deals with audio?  If so you shouldn't be surprised that this happens, that's a known bad practice.  Those things change with OEM and by version

Comment: R.string.audioapp = com.android.audioapp. I have updated the code in post. Please guide if possible. I just want the app to open com.android.audioapp when it is available. It works in Android 29 but does not work in Android 30.

Comment: You can't rely on package names like that.  There is no promise that they remain stable between versions, or that OEMs don't replace them with their own thing.

Comment: I understand your point. If that is the case then what is the best way to open the other app from within the app. Both apps are mine. Please guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android 11 added restrictions regarding the visibility of other apps. Apps that have `targetSdk` set to >= 30 can't interact with and open other apps without specifying this in the manifest.

To specify that your app interacts with another specific app, you need to add a `<queries>` element to your manifest file:

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.android.audioapp" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

The link below contains other examples in case you need to specify a broader range of apps which you want to interact with.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility

Comment: I added this to manifest, but I cannot start up it. What it can be?

Comment: @greg I think it makes sense for you to create a new question and specify what you have tried and what error you get in your logs (if any).